# Shared library: state and diamond

Tags: shared-libraries, diamond-problem

Let's say I have an application that calls libraries liba.so and libb.so.

Both of those libraries link to libc.so.

If licc.so keeps some state information, will this state be the same for liba.so and libb.so?

If yes, is there a way to make it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

> Both of those libraries link to libc.so.

The `libc.so` is special on UNIX: it's the `C` runtime support library. I'll assume that you didn't really mean `libc.so`, and are asking "if both `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` link to `libbaz.so` ...".

> If licc.so keeps some state information, will this state be the same for liba.so and libb.so?

If `libbaz.so` has private data symbol `int baz`, there will only be a single instance of `baz`, so yes: the state will be the same.

> is there a way to make it otherwise?

Some operating systems (notably Solaris and Linux) allow you to dynamically load `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` into separate linker namespaces using `dlmopen`. Doing this would also load `libbaz.so` twice, and there would be two instances (copies) of the `baz` symbol. Beware: this is not portable,  hard to get right, and hard to debug.